# When is Shivopasana Mantra chanted generally as per tradition? Can it be chanted independently as Nitya Parayana?

Tags: vedas, mantras

I am aware that Shivopasana Mantra is chanted during Rudra Abhishekams usually after Sri Rudram Namakam and Chamakam but my question is if it is suitable/appropriate to chant Shivopasana Mantra independently as a daily personal Sadhana? I mean just chanting Shivopasana Mantra without chanting Sri Rudram prior to it and without Abhishekam.